# Spark Streaming: Using external data during stream transformation

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have a situation where I have to filter data-points in a stream based on some condition involving a reference to external data. I have loaded up the external data in a Dataframe (so that I get to query on it using SQL interface). But when I tried to query on Dataframe I see that we cannot access it inside the transform (filter) function. (sample code below)

```
    // DStream is created and temp table called 'locations' is registered
    dStream.filter(dp => {
             val responseDf = sqlContext.sql("select location from locations where id='001'")
             responseDf.show()  //nothing is displayed
             // some condition evaluation using responseDf
             true
    })
```

Am I doing something wrong? If yes, then what would be a better approach to load external data in-memory and query it during stream transformation stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SparkSession instead of SQLContext solved the issue. Code below,

```
          val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("APP").getOrCreate()
          val df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(locationRepo.getLocationInfo, classOf[LocationVO])
          df.createOrReplaceTempView("locations")

          val dStream: DStream[StreamDataPoint] = getdStream()

          dStream.filter(dp => {
                 val sparkAppSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("APP").getOrCreate()
                 val responseDf = sparkAppSession.sql("select location from locations where id='001'")
                 responseDf.show()  // this prints the results
                 // some condition evaluation using responseDf
                 true
          })
```